# Explicitly typing variables causes compiler to think an instance of a builtin type doesn't have a property, which it does

Tags: actionscript-3, constructor, types, compiler-errors, explicit

I narrowed the causes of an AS3 compiler error 1119 down to code that looks similar to this:

```
var test_inst:Number = 2.953;
trace(test_inst);
trace(test_inst.constructor);
```

I get the error "1119: Access of possibly undefined property constructor through a reference with static type Number."

Now if I omit the variable's type, I don't get that error:

```
var test_inst = 2.953;
trace(test_inst);
trace(test_inst.constructor);
```

it produces the expected output:

```
2.953
[class Number]
```

So what's the deal? I like explicitly typing variables, so is there any way to solve this error other than not providing the variable's type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, this is a little hard to explain ... first of all, here is how it works:

```
var test_inst:Number = 2.953;
trace(test_inst);
trace((test_inst as Object).constructor);
```

to my understanding, this comes from the fact, that the property `constructor` comes from the ECMAScript-nature of ActionScript 3. It is an ECMAScript property of `Object` instances and is inherited through [prototypes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based_programming). From the strictly typed world of ActionScript 3 (which also uses a different inheritance mechanism), this property is thus not available.

greetz
back2dos

Comment: That's right. It'll also work if you compile without strict mode -- which is not really recommended.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showpost.php?p=1951137&postcount=214

that has all the info you need :)

basically, trace(test_inst["constructor"]) will work.

Answer (score 0):

Object(someobject).constructor will achieve the same thing -- and you don't have to deal with compiler issues.

Object(someinst) === someclass works as well.

dh